# android - Intent to response Dropbox and Google Drive

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get one Intent type in Android 5.0 that when I try to open one pdf document, Android show Dropbox and Google Drive alternatives. If I set my intent as **Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT** I get one explorer with Google Drive and Recents, documents, ... but not Dropbox. If i set my intent as **Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT** I get Dropbox but not Google Drive. Any way to get the two options? Any solution to get these two providers? In Android 4.2.2, with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, Google Drive was an option.

Like I said, my type is pdf:

```
intent.setType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: you got the solution ?